# Linux, how to ask DHCP to assign a specific IP address

Tags: linux, linux-networking, dhcp

I've recently purchased a tiny PC, on which I want to install Proxmox VE.
Currently I don't have any access to my landlord's router, therefore I don't know how big current DHCP pool is (and if there're some IPs excluded from the pool).

Is it possible to ask to the DHCP server for one or more specific IP address of my choice to keep that one forever?

Comment: Are you searching for a recipe to circumvent Proxmox VE requirement to have an IP statically configured?

Comment: Talk to your landlord.

Comment: What DHCP client are you using?

Comment: @MarkWagner isc-dhclient-4.4.1

Answer (score 2):

posting a section of debian man page for dhclient.conf :

```
fixed-address ip-address;

       The  fixed-address  statement is used
       to set the ip address of a particular
       lease.   This  is  required  for  all
       lease  statements.   The  IP  address
       must  be  specified  as a dotted quad
       (e.g., 12.34.56.78).
```

so by modifying /etc/dhclient.conf you should be able to request a fixed IP if the dhcp server doesn't reject such request.

Answer (score -2):

there is not a way to "ask" the DHCP server for a specific address.

this IS a way for the DHCP server to be configured to reserve a specific address for a specific computer (by MAC address usually).

depending on where your DHCP server is the way to do the reservation will be different.

Comment: This is wrong. [RFC2131 section 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131#section-3.1) says: "*The DHCPDISCOVER message MAY include options that suggest values for the network address and lease duration.*" This is precisely the way built into the protocol how to request a particular IP address from a DHCP server. The client is supposed to do this every time, to possibly have the same address again ([4.3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131#section-4.3.1)), but the server may refuse (NAK). The question was how to make use of this with the Debian network configuration.